# How to compile Object(*.o) files added with iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I have created a simple native iPhone app. This project contains with c,c++ source files for doing some operations. Its radio tuning app, thats work fine. I want to give a source code to some one, and want hide all of source code c,cpp file (Because strangers don't want to see my code). So what i did is , i have compiled iPhone app and collect all (.o) files from build path and added to my resource folder.

For example if my application have these two files

```
      radio.c
      radio.h
```

when i build **radio.o** present on build path directory. my build path is (/Users/Macuser/Projects/Radio//build/Radio.build/Release-iphoneos/HDRadio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/**radio.o**).

So i copied **radio.o** file and added to my source code directory, and i removed the radio.c and radio.h file. When i compile it gives a error, radio.h file not found.

What could be the problem here? please let me know. Thanks in advance..

Note:
When i add radio.h file to my project it compiles successfully. I don't want to see my radio.h and radio.m file. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some other file in your project that is importing or including radio.h.  Your .o file is used for linking but import/include dependencies are resolved when compiling the source.  (A .o file is **not** source.)

If you don't want to provide .h files, the way around that is to create a static library to contain all the .o files that depend on each other.  (However, to call any functions inside your library, the person still needs a .h with the declaration of public functions.)

Comment: Thanks. So when we create a static Library the .h files not viewed. right.

Comment: A static library by itself is a package of .o files contained in a .a (archive) file.  You only need the .h at compile time; once the objects are built, the .h is unnecessary **unless another source file needs to know the definition of some routine inside the library**.

Comment: yes got it. The .h file is a only identification of what we did in our library. Is there any possible combine this all .o file into a single .o file ? what could be the extension of static library ?

Comment: A .a (archive) file is a collection of .o files.